# How to make a ChangeListener with a JSlider to control Volume

Tags: java, jslider, jlayer, changelistener

im trying to make a changelistener that controls the volume of a music player, problem is i get a cannot find symbol error on the changelistener, is there an import i am missing or what. any information could help

```
    JSlider vol = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,min, max, init);
    vol.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
    vol.setMinorTickSpacing(2);
    vol.setMinorTickSpacing(3);
    vol.setMinorTickSpacing(4);
    vol.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
    vol.setMinorTickSpacing(6);
    vol.setMinorTickSpacing(7);
    vol.setMinorTickSpacing(8);
    vol.setMinorTickSpacing(9);
    vol.setMinorTickSpacing(10);



    vol.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
    {

        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
        {

            JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
            val = source.getValue();    


        }

    });
```

Comment: In case u're using eclipse, there is a command that organizes imports automatically (default is `Ctrl+Shift+o`).

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem similar to this and I believe if you don't have

import javax.swing.event.*;

it won't work.  Try importing that and hopefully it works for you!